# Why do I lose the original element when I `clone` inside an `each`?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.8, jquery-clone

I am trying to make my own `clone` function, but am running into a problem. I can use jQuery's `clone` function in my own without problem like this:`

```
$.prototype.cloneDumpingEvents = function () {
    return $(this).clone();
};
```

(Or, see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/dCm59/2/)

But if I try to make it work for collections of elements (adding `each`), it removes the original:

```
$.prototype.cloneDumpingEvents = function () {
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).clone();
    });
};
```

(Or, see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/dCm59/3/)

Why does the second version remove the original?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're returning the original instead of the clone. Use this instead:

```
$.fn.cloneDumpingEvents = function () {

    var collection = $();

    this.each(function() {
        collection = collection.add( $(this).clone() );
    });

    return collection;
};
```

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dCm59/4/

---

As pointed out by @FabrícioMatté in the comments, [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) is way shorter:

```
$.fn.cloneDumpingEvents = function () {
    return this.map(function() {
        return $.clone(this);
    });
};
```

Here's your fiddle again: http://jsfiddle.net/dCm59/7/

Comment: It works, but I don't understand. I'm not even using the return value, so why is it removing the original element?

Comment: @Shawn Because `.each()` returns the original jQuery object which it iterated over.

Comment: @Shawn - Of course you're using the return value: `p.cloneDumpingEvents().text('myClone')...`. See, the original element was never removed. It's just that you changed its text, so you thought you were looking at your new element.

Comment: Oh I see. I hadn't understood @FabrícioMatté 's first comment. Thanks.

Comment: BTW Joseph, I believe this task can be made in a simpler way with [`jQuery.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/): http://jsfiddle.net/dCm59/5/ Free free to add to your answer.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - You're right. But why, in every step in the loop, are your creating a new jQuery object only to then abandon it?

Comment: @JosephSilber Object creation is necessary to be able to call `.clone()` on it. The `[0]` just takes a property lookup so I can return an array of DOM elements, I believe it should be faster than returning many jQuery objects that get fused into one. But it might need some JSPerfs to be sure.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Did you check my answer?

Comment: Yeah I +1'd it, though I can't find documentation for `jQuery.clone`, I believe it is an internal lower-level method for the `jQuery.fn.clone`?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Many of the jQuery methods are also available as static methods. `.css`, `.attr`, `.data` etc. Paul Irish (which at some point was among the leading jQuery developers) advises using the static methods whenever possible.

Comment: @JosephSilber Yes I've seen the use of `$.data` before, though I wasn't aware that this was available. Thanks for the info. `=]`

Comment: I checked out your fiddle and yes, your answer is much better performance-wise as you return the same value as mine but without creating an extra object in each iteration. Though I may be still a bit afraid of using undocumented methods, this is very useful knowledge. Thanks again.